# React Native Touchable Opacity Issue

Tags: react-native, key, react-props, touchableopacity

I am trying to create a Button/Icon Component updates icon image based on the url I am linking the user to. For example I have a movie object and I want to link users to imdb and rotten tomatoes. I want that component to show the icon for rotten tomatoes when linking the rotten tomatoes deep link and the imdb icon when linking imdb url.

I am rendering the data from an array.  For example:

```
const Movie = [
{ key: 1,
tile: Good Will Hunting
icon1:'./images/imdb.png',
url1: 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119217/?ref_=nv_sr_1',
icon2:'./images/rottentomatoes'
url2: 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/good_will_hunting'

    <View>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleOpenWithLinkingUrlOne}>
                  <Image
                    source={require("url one icon")}
                    style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>

       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleOpenWithLinkingUrlTwo}>
                  <Image
                    source={require("url two icon")}
                    style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
                  />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>


    _handleOpenWithLinkingUrlOne = () => {
        Linking.openURL("data from url two");
      };
    _handleOpenWithLinkingUrlTwo = () => {
        Linking.openURL("data from url two");

  };
```

How can I pull the data from the object to both so it renders the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data on state and then use `source={{uri: this.state.movie.uri1}}` or `source={{uri: this.state.movie.uri2}}` on Image component

Comment: Setting the state on the image will pull the icon I want to use but will not set the url I want to take the user to.  How do I pass the data through the touchable opacity so that openURL below is pulled from the object data as well.                                                                                   <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleOpenWithWebBrowser}>                          
                                                                                 
 _handleOpenWithLinking = () => {
    Linking.openURL("url to link user too- need to pull data to here");

Comment: Alessandro can you help me? I want to pass a url through_handleOpenWithLinking = () => { Linking.openURL("url to link user too- need to pull data to here");

Comment: Sorry, but i cant understand what are you trying to do, maybe this?onPress={this._handleOpenWithLinkingUrlTwo(url)} _handleOpenWithLinkingUrlOne = (url) => {
        Linking.openURL(url);
      }; 
I need more information about the code. You want to pass a user data + movie url data? can you provide a full url example?

Comment: maybe this could help https://gist.github.com/macanhajc/8b01e3aefb648d160e0e5c150ca39ed6

Comment: Thank you so much for help. Your solution is almost correct. The issue is now the app open directly to the imdb url without pressing it?  Can you trying to fix that issue so the link open until user presses the actual button?

Comment: try change <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleOpenWithLinkingUrlOne(movie.url1)}> to <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._handleOpenWithLinkingUrlOne(movie.url1)}>

Comment: That solved the issue of the app not opening directly to the link but now I can not get anything to render to the screen? Can you add the same code for the button so I can get a visual and see if it works. Or add a container with the movie poster. I really really appreciate your help. I have been working on this for awhile now trying to come up with a linking solution

Comment: Ok, first inside the map we need a return() to show the data, the TouchableOpacity will not appear unless the image is shown, so to avoid that we put a size on it or we can put the size on image too.
Fixed
https://gist.github.com/macanhajc/8b01e3aefb648d160e0e5c150ca39ed6

Comment: This is great! How do I pull the icon image as the button image instead of green and red?

Comment: Just remove the style from touchableoppacity and put on Image like the first button, then remove the backgroundColor and on uri put the icon url

Comment: Alessandro Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Alessandro what is the best way to store the movie data and pull it so it renders only when in window. I know virtualized list is a way to do this. I want make sure that runs quickly and limited resources are being used. Any thouughts on using graphql and redux? Should I use mongodb for database?